# CDT : Parsing enumerations, enumerators and corresponding values

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing an extension of eclipse CDT plug-in which has to parse the c++ code and find all

- enumerations (names)
- enumerators (names)
- enumerator values (numbers)

Suppose .cpp file contains following text

```
enum SomeEnum
{
   One            = 0,
   Two            = 1,
   Three          = 2,
   Four           = 3,
   maxNum
};
```

The pluging should output following :

- Enumeration - **SomeEnum**
- Enumerators - **One, Two, Three, Four,    maxNum**
- Values      - **0, 1, 2, 3,**

The visitor method of ASTVisitor inherited class finds the enumerations this way

```java
public int visit(IASTDeclaration declaration) {
    if (declaration instanceof IASTSimpleDeclaration) {

        IASTDeclSpecifier specifier = ((IASTSimpleDeclaration)declaration).getDeclSpecifier();

        if (specifier instanceof IASTEnumerationSpecifier) {

            IASTEnumerationSpecifier enumSpecifier = (IASTEnumerationSpecifier)specifier;
            IBinding binding = enumSpecifier.getName().resolveBinding(); 
            System.out.println(enumSpecifier.getName());
        }
    }
    return PROCESS_CONTINUE;
}
```

**Question :** How can I iterate over the enumerators and their corresponding values of found enumeration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well figured out on my own

```
public int visit(IASTDeclaration declaration) {
    if (declaration instanceof IASTSimpleDeclaration) { 
        IASTDeclSpecifier specifier = ((IASTSimpleDeclaration)declaration).getDeclSpecifier();
        if (specifier instanceof IASTEnumerationSpecifier) {
            IASTEnumerationSpecifier enumSpecifier = (IASTEnumerationSpecifier)specifier;
            // Get the current enumeration name
            String enumerationName = enumSpecifier.getName().toString();
            IASTEnumerator[] enumerators = enumSpecifier.getEnumerators();
            for (IASTEnumerator enumerator : enumerators)
            {
                System.out.println(enumerator.getName());
                if (enumerator.getValue() instanceof IASTLiteralExpression  ) {
                    System.out.println(enumerator.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return PROCESS_CONTINUE;
}
```